# Better way to query server-provided fields in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm thinking about moving our API from a standard HTTP endpoint to GraphQL.
On the client we have data tables in which the user can choose what columns they want to have visible.
Users can save their column layout for the next time they open the application.

The problem is the first time such a table is shown, the client requires two things:

- What columns has the user saved
- The data of these columns for each record

Currently we have a single endpoint returning both of these in JSON.

URL: `/contacts/table`

```
{
    "columns": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "rows": [
        { 
            "a": 0, 
            "b": 1,
            "c": 2 
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a nice way to get the above working in a GraphQL API?

## Some things I've tried:

- Have an API that returns key value pairs

  ```
  "columns": ["a", "b", "c"]
  "rows": [
      [
          {
              "key": "a"
              "value": 0
          },
          {
              "key": "b"
              "value": 1
          }
      ]
  ]
  ```

  Problems with this approach:

  1. It has a lot of overhead
  2. It feels like reinventing the wheel seeing as JSON is already key/value based.
  3. Doesn't work well with caching frameworks such as apollo when the same type needs to be accessed in a non-table way
- Custom syntax

  ```
  query {
    tables {
      contacts {
       columns @provideFragment("ContactColumns")
      } 
    }

    contacts {
      ..ContactsColumns
    }
  }
  ```

  Problems with this approach:

  1. It's not standard (as far as I know), so it might not work with other tooling.

Comment: Great question. I think without a non-standard extension (like [query batching](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/new-features-in-graphql-batch-defer-stream-live-and-subscribe-7585d0c28b07), that might go into the spec one day), you're stuck with your first approach.

Comment: Thanks. The query batching looks promising, I'll have a look at it.